# ContentEditable on nextjs, update not showing in state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable, next.js

i got a component for a message. I got there a ContentEditable component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable i use there because i would need to add contacts in this "textarea" but i needed to implement html code inside for separate every tag, give them a color, etc.

The problem is that i want to prevent characters, user will not be able to add letters, just numbers, comma, and space. I created a function for this for use "onChange", it shows me the right data in the console. But in the frame it stills show the ilegal characters that the user has typed in. The correct data is in the state, but it does not update on the ContentEditable frame.

```
  const contentEditable = React.createRef();
  let state = { html: "0424" };

  const handleChange = evt => {


    let htmlf = evt.target.value.replace(/\D/g,''); ;
    console.log(htmlf);
    state = { html: htmlf };
    console.log(state);
  };



        <ContentEditable
          innerRef={contentEditable}
          html={state.html} // innerHTML of the editable div
          disabled={false} // use true to disable editing
          onChange={handleChange} // handle innerHTML change
          tagName="numero" // Use a custom HTML tag (uses a div by default)
          id="contacts"
        />
```

**SOLUTION**

Just declare the component state in a different way.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      html: "0424"
    };

  }

  contentEditable = React.createRef();

  handleChange = evt => {
    let htmlf = evt.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    console.log(htmlf);
    this.setState({ html: htmlf })
    console.log(this.state);
  };

<ContentEditable
            innerRef={this.contentEditable}
            html={this.state.html} // innerHTML of the editable div
            disabled={false} // use true to disable editing
            onChange={this.handleChange} // handle innerHTML change
            tagName="numero" // Use a custom HTML tag (uses a div by default)
            id="contacts"
          />
```